# Is there a way for a combobox to get unique info from enum depending on user selection?

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

So I am doing some revision in preparation for a uni GUI exam.

My Enum has a list of >20 items that all have a unique name and cost.
This is my current enum

```
public enum List
{
    Brush ("Brush", 2),
    Clock ("Brush", 5);
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private List(String name, int cost)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

I want the user to select an item option in which it references the enum and gets the specific name and cost so I can output it into cost calculations and print lines. How would I be able to do that? All I know is that it can use indexes to search for it but I'm not too sure.

Comment: what's stopping you from adding getters? But, honestly, I would urge you to reconsider using enums for this. This doesn't seem like something you would want enums for

Comment: @Stultuske what's stopping you from making that the answer?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff the fact that, from the setup of the code/logic and question, I'm not entirely sure what the OP is trying to achieve. I usually reserve answers for when I'm a bit more sure

Comment: I agree with Stultuske: you should get clear on your "mental model" first. Note that you called your enum "List" ... which is not what it does, as it gives you different shopping list ITEMS. The point of enums is to give you a type that knows all potential instantiations already at compile time. But think about it: no shopping catalogue knows the number of different entries it will have tomorrow. So: rather design a class that represents a "shopping list item" (with price, name, id, ...). Then research how to use models in Swing ...

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html for example.